# What is the default path for local Prezi files?

Tags: windows, presentations

I recently had to reinstall Windows 10 on my PC.

It appears that I had not saved all of my Prezi files to the cloud. I still have the old disc image and would like to find the location of the local Prezi files so that I could transfer them to my current environment.

I am running `Prezi for Windows 6.16.2.0`.

Where might that be?

Comment: Have you tried installing Prezi on your pc again and looking where does it save your files by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default location that local prezis will be saved is:

`C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Prezi\Content\<uniqueID>`

`UniqueID` will be something like 
On OSX they will be saved under"

`/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/com.prezi.desktop/<uniqueID>/content`

Where uniqueID will be something like `0000000002b4abd4`.